# Сравнение элементов списка по парам по очереди в Python

Tags: python, list

Сравнение элементов списка по парам по очереди, и вывод данных сколько раз первое число было больше второго, сколько раз раз первое число было равно второму? 3 число из списка сравнить с 4, 5 с 6 итд.

Опишу задачу, человек решил бегать каждый день, и хочет значть в какой из дней он бегал больше чем в предыдущий, именно сравнения должны по очереди идти, а не сравнивать со всеми днями.
Мой говнокод выглядит так,

```
listA = []
day = int(input("Дней бега:"))

for day in range(0, day):
    km = float(input("КМ в день: "))
    listA.append(km)
    
print("Вы бегали", day+1,   "дней по", *listA, "км.") 

if listA[0] == listA[1]:
    print("Не было улучшений")
elif listA[0] >= list[1]:
```

если сравнить два первых элемента списка я еще понял как, то как сделать так чтобы если в списке было 10 дней то он сделал 5 сравнений? и если 20 то 10! так как каждый раз лист состоит из разного количества элементов...
и также нужно чтобы Python вывел в "print" мне все данные типа когда было улучшение? а когда его не было? и самое важное мне важно знать сколько в принципе раз было улучшение? ("Вы улучшили свой результат 3 раза" напримре так)

Перевод задания с немецкого

"Гюнтер хочет подготовиться к марафону. для этого он бегает по субботам
• Он измеряет каждую пробежку. Он хочет узнать, как часто текущий пробег лучше предыдущего.
• Гюнтер называет этот сценарий «улучшением».
Создайте функцию, которая получает список километров пробега за день в качестве параметра и выводит, как часто Гюнтер имеет "улучшение"."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посчитать количество дней с большим пробегом, чем в предыдущий. Сравнений будет, кстати, 9 для 10 дней (n-1)

```
largecnt = 0
for day in range(1, len(listA)):
    if listA[day] > listA[day-1]:
         largecnt+=1
print('дней с увеличением: ', largecnt)
```

Можно добавить

```
    if lista[i] > listA[i-1]:
         largecnt+=1
         ещё чего-то делать
    elif  lista[i] == listA[i-1]:    
        так же
    else:
         хуже
```

Comment: мне кажется место `range(1, len(listA))` надо писать `range(1, len(listA), 2)`

Comment: @Danis Я думаю, есть противоречие между постановкой задачи `хочет знать в какой из дней он бегал больше чем в предыдущий` и интерпретацией автора `3 число из списка сравнить с 4, 5 с 6 итд`

Comment: в какой из дней если сравнивать данные из списка по парам

Comment: @Aleksandr Pavlov Приведите точную формулировку задания

Comment: перевод с немецкого 
Гюнтер хочет подготовиться к марафону. для этого он бегает по субботам
•
Он измеряет каждую пробежку. Он хочет узнать, как часто
текущий пробег лучше предыдущего.
•
Гюнтер называет этот сценарий «улучшением».

Создайте функцию, которая получает список километров пробега за день в качестве параметра и выводит, как часто Гюнтер имеет "улучшение".

Comment: ОК, значит, моё толкование верное. Если брать пары по отдельности, то как будет сравниваться третий день с предыдущим - вторым? Сравнения должны быть 1-2 2-3 3-4 4-5

Comment: я тоже думал об этом, есть идея тогда как сделать то что Вы предлжили? сравнивая каждый день с последующим и выводя сколько раз такое улучшение было?

Comment: Так я это и сделал в коде

Comment: Спасибо большущее, не работало пока [i] и [i-1] не заменил на [day] и [day-1]

Comment: Да, это я упустил

Comment: теперь вопрос следующий, теперь когда у меня было два улучшение в листе, он мне дважды пишет после "print" 
 Вы улучшились 1 раз 
Вы улучшились 2 раза
Как сделать так чтобы он выдывал в результат в принт только послдний результат, потому что улучщений может быть 10, и он 10 раз мне пишет

Comment: если print стоит **после цикла**, как у меня написано, вывод будет только один раз